# Redirect a page using .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have a website which is in cache and can not be removed. It is working fine if i use `nocache=1` in front of the link. I want to redirect link `http://www.link.com` to `http://www.link.com/?nocache=1`.

I have tried using

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Redirect 301 / http://www.link.com/?nocache=1
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

But did not get it right. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add `nocache=1` to all request before Wordpress Dispatcher:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?nocache=1 [QSA]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `Redirect 301` rule with this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)nocache=1(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?nocache=1 [L,QSA,R=302]
```

And make sure it is just below `RewriteEngine On` line

Comment: How is that comment going to help you?

Comment: Need answers of all of these questions. Q0. What URL are you entering in your browser? Q1. Is this the only .htaccess or do you have another? Q2. Is this the only code in this .htaccess? If you have some other code then please post it in question? Q3. What is full path of above .htaccess?